# Is there a difference in checking if an integer is equal to 0 or not False

Tags: python, evaluation

So, as far as I am aware, there are two distinct ways of checking whether an integer is `0` in Python. We can either do:

```
if i == 0:
    ...
```

or

```
if not i:
    ...
```

The first could be argued to be clearer, but are there any cases where they produce different results or one performs better?

Comment: This doesn't apply when `i` is an integer, but if `i = []` then the behavior is different.

Comment: `if not` checks the `truthy` while `==` tries to match the value, generally speaking, if you just want to check the truthy `if not` or `if i` is faster

Comment: If you know `i` is an integer, then there's no difference. Use whichever is clearer.

Comment: As for performance, I can't think of a situation where this kind of micro-optimization would make any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference. You can decompile the byte code using `dis` to observe what happens at the lowest level.

```
import dis

dis.dis("if i == 0: pass")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (i)
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
              6 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
              9 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       15
             12 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 15)
        >>   15 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE
```

`i` is explicitly compared to the constant value `0`, as you see on line `6 COMPARE_OP`. Meanwhile, for the latter case -

```
dis.dis("if not i: pass")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (i)
              3 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE         9
              6 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 9)
        >>    9 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

You'll see the "truthiness" of `i` is tested. Anything in python that has a false-y value (`0`, `0.0`, `False`, empty strings and empty containers) are all considered to be `False`, so the resultant expression is `True`.

What you use depends on what you want to test for. Do you want to test the false-ness of an object? Or do you want to test whether the value is `0`? The latter is a lot more specific, and slightly different from a semantic perspective.

Oh, and if we're talking performance, then -

```
%timeit if i == 0: pass
10000000 loops, best of 3: 51.4 ns per loop

%timeit if not i: pass
10000000 loops, best of 3: 39.1 ns per loop
```

`not i` is not only pythonic, but faster (albeit not by much, and results may vary on different machines and python versions).

Comment: Hmm, can you put your full `timeit` case, in my case `==` was faster than using `if not i`

Comment: @user1767754 I timed this in python3.4, Ipython5.2, on a MacOSX. Timings are likely to vary across machines and implementations, I've added that disclaimer.

Answer (score 1):

Speedwise there is almost no difference, however `==` performed `~3%` better on my system with `1000` run's on a `10**7` comparison loop. Furthermore that's an optimization you shouldn't be hardly thinking of, especially using python.

Doing a query like `if not i` or `if i` is checking the truthy of the given value. where the number `0` evaluates to `false`, anything smaller or greater to `true`. 
Again, before actually deciding for which one, you should ask yourself the question if you are looking for the **truthy** or a **comparision**  with a specific value.

Answer (score 1):

```
if i == 0
```

will only be true if `i` is equal to `0` or when `i` is `False`, whereas

```
if not i
```

will be true when `i` is 0, when `i` is `False`, but also when `i` is an empty collection.

Depending on what you're trying to do, one may be better than the other.

There may be a *very* slight performance benefit with using the latter solution, but this is negligible. Clarity and correctness of your code is much more important.

Comment: You comment about which cases `False` will trigger is not true. `bool` is a subclass of `int`. They are defined such that: `True == 1` and `False == 0`. (Use empty collections (`[], {}, ()`) instead of `False` in your answer).

Comment: @Dunes That's a good point. Thanks for pointing it out to me!